Lighting doesn't work in Unity with built in URP
I made a Unity project via the 3D URP, and I've been trying to use lighting thru sprite renderers, and 3d objects, however it doesn't work.. At all.

I'm trying to test to see if a red light would work, however it doesn't (as seen above).
It could be either the material, or something wrong with my URP settings.
Once again, I made the Unity project via the Universal 3D.
No sprite renderers and 3D objects are affected by the light.
I tried changing the material, and tried changing the URP settings. I've also done some more research.
None of those things helped.

Sprites (by default) have a 2D material, which will only react to 2D lights. Ensure that you have lighting in the scene view enabled (through the lightbulb icon in the top right of the scene view window), and your materials use URP's 3D Lit shaders

Ah ok, thank you. I will try that.
